# How do I add a thumbnail to my website so that when someone shares a link on Twitter or Facebook it shows the image and the link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, hyperlink

How do I add a thumbnail to my website so when a user shares the link to Twitter or Facebook it shows the link with the image in HTML and Javascript? 
So what I exactly want is that when the user shares the link of my website on any social media a thumbnail image comes beside it.

I've put a link of what I want below.

https://twitter.com/Medium/status/634152899132592128

Comment: show your code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called twitter cards and basically, you add `<meta>` tags to your page to tell Twitter what to show on them.

I think the type of card you are looking for is this one:
https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Here is a snippet with examples how it would work (taken from the docs):

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

They even provide you with a service to validate and preview the cards:
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

---

For Facebook, the `<meta>` tags are different and are also well documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

As with Twitter, they also provide a page where you can validate and preview:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Hope that helps!

Comment: It says "WARN:  Not whitelisted". How do I fix this?

Comment: @user3675276 seems like cards with videos need to be whitelisted before they work. This should help you get it approved: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/troubleshooting#approval

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will look for

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://weekendtrails.com/screenshot.png" />
```

U can use this meta tag for facebook. I hope it will work with other sites also